# Get week ranges based off start date and number of given weeks

Tags: swift

I have a start date of July 13, 2020 and an Int representing the number of weeks that I have chosen, in this case five. I would like to print each week range for those five weeks. Example of the expected output:

1. July 13 - July 19
2. July 20 - July 26
3. July 27 - August 2
4. August 3 - August 9
5. August 10 - August 16

With the code below, I'm able to get the first two weeks however, the weeks should continue to print depending on the input of weeks.

```
func getRanges() {
    let arrWeekDates = rangeString!.getWeekDates() // Get dates of two weeks.
    let dateFormat = "MMM dd"
    let thisMon = arrWeekDates.thisWeek.first!.toDate(format: dateFormat)
    let thisSun = arrWeekDates.thisWeek[arrWeekDates.thisWeek.count - 1].toDate(format: dateFormat)

    let nextMon = arrWeekDates.nextWeek.first!.toDate(format: dateFormat)
    let nextSun = arrWeekDates.nextWeek[arrWeekDates.nextWeek.count - 1].toDate(format: dateFormat)

    print("This Week: \(thisMon) - \(thisSun)")
    print("Next Week: \(nextMon) - \(nextSun)")
    
}

extension Date {

func getWeekDates() -> (thisWeek:[Date],nextWeek:[Date]) {
        var tuple: (thisWeek:[Date],nextWeek:[Date])
        var arrThisWeek: [Date] = []
        for i in 0..<7 {
            arrThisWeek.append(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: startOfWeek)!)
        }
        var arrNextWeek: [Date] = []
        for i in 1...7 {
            arrNextWeek.append(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: arrThisWeek.last!)!)
        }
        tuple = (thisWeek: arrThisWeek,nextWeek: arrNextWeek)
        return tuple
    }

var startOfWeek: Date {
            let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))
            return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sunday!)!
        }
func toDate(format: String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a function that takes a starting date and the number of weeks as arguments and returns an array of `DateInterval` for the week start and end dates

```
func weeks(from date: Date, duration: Int) -> [DateInterval]? {
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    //Get date for first day of the week
    let diff = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date) - calendar.firstWeekday
    guard let firstDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -(diff < 0 ? 7 + diff : diff), to: date) else {
        return nil
    }

    //Generate start and end date for the duration 
    var weeks = [DateInterval(start: firstDate, end: calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: firstDate)!)]
    for week in 1..<duration {
        guard let firstDayOfWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: weeks[week - 1].start),
            let lastDayOfWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: firstDayOfWeek) else { return nil }

        weeks.append(DateInterval(start: firstDayOfWeek, end: lastDayOfWeek))
    }
    return weeks
}
```

and to use it and print the dates you can do

```
if let weeks = weeks(from: Date(), duration: 5) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd"

    for interval in weeks {
        print("\(formatter.string(from: interval.start)) -  \(formatter.string(from: interval.end))")
    }
}
```

which outputs

> July 13 -  July 19
> July 20 -  July 26
> July 27 -  August 02
> August 03 -  August 09
> August 10 -  August 16

Answer (score 0):

Recently my need was to get a range of weeks from given dates, so for that, I've made some changes in @joakim-danielson answer and developed a code as per my requirement.

```
var startDateString = "01/10/2022"
var endDateString = "31/03/2023"
var df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let startDate = df.date(from: startDateString)!
let endDate = df.date(from: endDateString)!

func weeks(from date: Date, toDate: Date) -> [DateInterval]? {
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let diff = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date) - calendar.firstWeekday
    guard let firstDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -(diff < 0 ? 7 + diff : diff), to: date) else {
        return nil
    }

    let sunday = Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: toDate))
    let startDateOfWeek = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sunday!)
    
    var weeks = [DateInterval(start: firstDate, end: calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: firstDate)!)]
    
    var actualFirstDate = Date()
    var i: Int = 1
    
    repeat {
        guard let firstDayOfWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: weeks[i - 1].start),
              let lastDayOfWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: firstDayOfWeek) else { return nil }
        weeks.append(DateInterval(start: firstDayOfWeek, end: lastDayOfWeek))
        actualFirstDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: firstDayOfWeek)!
        i += 1
    } while startDateOfWeek != actualFirstDate
    
    return weeks
}

if let weeks = weeks(from: startDate, toDate: endDate) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

    for interval in weeks {
        print("\(formatter.string(from: interval.start)) - \(formatter.string(from: interval.end))")
    }
}
```

Output:

> 25/09/2022 - 01/10/2022 
> 02/10/2022 - 08/10/2022 
> 09/10/2022 - 15/10/2022 
> 16/10/2022 - 22/10/2022 
> 23/10/2022 - 29/10/2022 
> 30/10/2022 - 05/11/2022 
> 06/11/2022 - 12/11/2022 
> 13/11/2022 - 19/11/2022 
> 20/11/2022 - 26/11/2022 
> 27/11/2022 - 03/12/2022 
> 04/12/2022 - 10/12/2022 
> 11/12/2022 - 17/12/2022 
> 18/12/2022 - 24/12/2022 
> 25/12/2022 - 31/12/2022 
> 01/01/2023 - 07/01/2023 
> 08/01/2023 - 14/01/2023 
> 15/01/2023 - 21/01/2023 
> 22/01/2023 - 28/01/2023 
> 29/01/2023 - 04/02/2023 
> 05/02/2023 - 11/02/2023 
> 12/02/2023 - 18/02/2023 
> 19/02/2023 - 25/02/2023 
> 26/02/2023 - 04/03/2023 
> 05/03/2023 - 11/03/2023 
> 12/03/2023 - 18/03/2023 
> 19/03/2023 - 25/03/2023 
> 26/03/2023 - 01/04/2023